# How to access multidimensional json array inside ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

**Details :**

Have a good day programmers. My server is returning me the multidimensional json array.Now i just want to access it individually and also i am little bit confused in JSON format.

**Question 1:** what is the difference between these Type1 and Type2  json format?

**JSON Type 1**

```
{
    "name": "Stackoverflow",
    "exp": "4month",
    "status": 
             {
               "username": "koushik",
               "password": "mypassword"
             }
}
```

**JSON Type 2**

```
{
    "name": "Stackoverflow",
    "exp": "4month",
    "status": [
        {
            "username": "koushik",
            "password": "mypassword"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know both are valid json format but where it differ's?

**Question 2:** Using ajax i can handle single dimention json data

**Example:** It works

```
$.ajax({
        url:"temp.json",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){     
                 alert(data.name);
        }
    });
```

In the same way how could i handle multidimensional json array.Example i want to get something like this **alert(data=>status=>username)**  . I know it is very easy to do but i am struck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not multi-dimensional. It's got one dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1: what is the difference between these Type1 and Type2 json format?**

In the first, the `status` property refers to an object (that in turn has two properties). In the second, the `status` property refers to an array, the first and only element of which is an object (that in turn has two properties).

**Question 2:**

For your "Type1" you can just do:

```
data.status.username
```

For your "Type2":

```
data.status[0].username
```

...or if a real-world case of "Type2" had an array with more objects in it you could loop over the items and do something with them:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.status.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.status[i].username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this -

```
$.each(data.status,function(i,v){
   console.log(v.username);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($.isArray(data.status)){
  // JSON Type 2
  $(data.status).each(function(){console.log(this.username);});

}
else
{
 //JSON Type 1
 console.log(data.status.username);
}
```